22 to 24 upgrade: "Please install all available updates", how?
I have used "settings/other software" to disable lyx-devel and zoneminder, to get past the initial problems. Now I get a request to install available upgrades.
No idea what to do next.
sudo apt list --upgradable yields:
libnetplan0/jammy-updates 0.107.1-3ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.106.1-7ubuntu0.22.04.4]
netplan.io/jammy-updates 0.107.1-3ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.106.1-7ubuntu0.22.04.4]
node-mkdirp/jammy,jammy 1.0.4+~1.0.2-1 all [upgradable from: 0.5.1-2]
node-nopt/jammy,jammy 5.0.0-2 all [upgradable from: 3.0.6-4]
node-pre-gyp/jammy,jammy 1.0.8+~1.0.3-1 all [upgradable from: 0.10.2-3]
node-tar/jammy,jammy 6.1.11+ds1+~cs6.0.6-1 all [upgradable from: 4.4.10+ds1-2ubuntu1]

Both sudo apt upgrade and sudo apt full-upgrade yield:
The following packages have been kept back:
  libnetplan0 netplan.io node-mkdirp node-nopt node-pre-gyp node-tar
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 6 not to upgrade.


What is the result of 'sudo apt upgrade' ? Or maybe 'sudo apt full-upgrade' ?

For both I get:  The following packages have been kept back:
libnetplan0 netplan.io node-mkdirp node-nopt node-pre-gyp node-tar
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 6 not to upgrade.

It appears those updates are being "phased in".
You can upgrade them with synaptic, with aptitude, or wait until Ubuntu phasing decides you are allowed to upgrade them.
(Waiting is safest, as user535733 points out in a comment, sometimes the phasing is stopped because an issue has been found).

netplan.io and associated packages are phased because a problem was reported (https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/phased-updates.html). You can override, but there is a risk you might encounter the same problem.

@user535733 Thanks for the comment. Updated the answer to mention that sometimes phasing stops due to very good reasons.
